# Hadoop benchmark tests

Tags: hadoop, testing, benchmarking

I am currently performing some tests in a small cluster (4 nodes) and I would like to know if there are any best practices regarding the node that actually launches the test scripts in the cluster. I am using test tools like hive-testbench and HiBench.

There should be no impact in the performance if I run a spark script in the same machine that is hosting the thrift server, or should I add another machine to the cluster just to launch the test/benchmark scripts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A 4-node cluster is not a reliable setup for benchmarking anything Hadoop related unless each node is a physical server (not VM!) with 16 core x 64 GB memory or higher.  You'll end up measuring memory contention and heap allocation latency more than anything else.

Comment: tk421 thank you for your feedback. However, assuming that the cluster has enough resources, should I add a new node just to launch the performance/benchmark scripts? Or is it safe to assume that the test scripts won't have influence in the results? Again, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I don't think kicking off the test on the cluster will matter assuming you have sufficient memory.  If your cluster is memory-bound you would probably see things like OOME and potentially services failing while running.